# Finding whether a number is prime or not c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)  return false;
    if (n <= 3)  return true;

    if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

    for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6)
        if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
           return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {
    int T,n;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
    cin>>n;
    isPrime(n)?  cout << "Prime\n": cout << "Not prime\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hey, so I am working on this code to find whether a number is a prime or not,
and I did lots of research but I am unable to find the working of this step.

in isprime() function

```
for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6)
if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
return false;
```

Please help me figure this out any help is appreciated

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the *desired behavior*, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: this code works perfectly fine, no need for debugging, and I have included that part of a function which I did not understand yet, and that is my question.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  Did you copy this code from somewhere and want to know how it works or is this your own code?

Comment: "_this code works perfectly fine_" and "_Please help me figure this out_". Without a proper question, pick one. I sincerely don't know what you expect of us. What is your question? You want us to explain those three lines of code?

Comment: See the Simple Method section https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: Try your program with the test case of 13, and 17.

Comment: Regardless of the algorithm you use, checking any number larger than `sqrt(n)` is pointless.

Comment: ya, this problem is from hackerank, and their time matters idk but scanning till sqrt(candidate) is not working, maybe I did some mistakes in the code

Comment: @kanishktanwar: Your code is correct. This should pass all test cases since I tried same approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop

```
for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6)
  if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0)
    return false;
```

could have been written as:

```
for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+2)
  if (n%i == 0 )
    return false;
```

for easier understanding. You check whether the number is divisible by:

```
5 7 9 11 13, etc.
```

If you rearrange those odd numbers as:

```
5 7 9
11 13 15
17 19 21
23 25 27
```

etc.,

you'll notice that the all the numbers in the last column are multiples of 3. If any number is divisible by those, they are divisible by 3 also. Since the function already checks whether the number is divisible by 3 at the beginning, it's not necessary to check that. Hence, we need to check whether the number is divisible only by:

```
5 7 
11 13
17 19
23 25
```

etc.

The patter for those number is:

```
i i+2
```

with the increment between the rows being 6. You can translate that to:

1. Start with `i = 5`
2. Check whether the number is divisible by `i` or `i+2`. If so, return `false`.
3. Increment `i` by `6` and repeat.

That's what the `for` loop does.

Why is the conditional of the `for` statement `i*i <= n`?

That's because a number cannot be divisible by any number greater than its square root.  If you reach the point where `i*i` > `n`, you are assured that `n` is not divisible by `i`. Continuing with the loop for any `i` greater than that will not change the value of the conditional. The number is a prime number when we reach that point.

Comment: nice explanation on point, little question in the loop for(int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+2) the testing part has i*i meaning the loop will continue until 25<=5 right? so why this loop still goes. I don't understand this testing condition at all gosh.

Comment: @kanishktanwar, The loop variable starts with 5. Hence, it will start with testing `25 < n`, not `25 < 5`. If `n` is 200, the first test will be `25 < 200`. The second test will be `11*11 < 200`. The third test will be `17*17 < 200`, etc.

Comment: that means when it reaches test condition 17 it will end right?

Comment: @kanishktanwar, I had a brain lapse there. You are right. It will stop when `i` is `17`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, at this point I am onto some other dimension, the only thing coming to my mind is just quit this, and sleep thanks for sharing the information,and on point explanation

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one of the classic algorithms for checking a prime nature of number. So basically, you are checking for divisibility by 2 and 3 right before the loop starts.

Then for checking with other numbers, you start from 5 and go till that `i*i = n`. That is because a number `n` which is divisible by any number `i` would always mean that number `i` is less than the square root of `n`. You can verify it through various examples. Say 37. Smallest number for which `i*i>n` is `6` and hence, you need to check it only till number `6` and not go beyond for checking ahead because all the other multiples you have already checked. So, if you don't find any number beyond `6` here, you need not to go further for check.

Second part is the other condition where you are incrementing by 2 for checking `if` condition. This is because you are starting the divisibility by `5` and incrementing it by `6` everytime. By doing this, you are ensuring that you only check possible prime numbers for the divisibility test and not any others.

I hope the logic is clear now. Feel free to ask any doubts you have in comments.

Comment: One issue is the incrementing by 6.  The prime numbers 13 and 17 slip through.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No they don't. Look at the code. If `13` and `17` are encountered, it will just check initial condition for divisibility by 2 and 3, won't go inside for loop and at last, return true. It would return true for `isPrime(13)` and `isPrime(17)` in my opinion.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 13 and 17 work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b9d02a1e29cc3d.  If you never enter the loop you still return true.

Comment: well I still can't understand that i*i here,

Comment: @kanishktanwar If `i * i == n`, what is `i`?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking opposite return values.

Comment: damn, i am editing my above comment and I cant because its above 5 minutes, I am asking is whether i*i part is a necessity, can we just sqrt(37) to get the desired answer?

Comment: @kanishktanwar `sqrt` is expensive.  `i * i` is much cheaper.

Comment: you can but for competitive filed, you should try `i*i` approach as compared to `sqrt` one.